# Does there exist a real function with domain $\Bbb{R}$ such that $f'(x)>0$ and $f''(x)+(f'(x))^2<0$ for all $x$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Does there exist a real function $f(x)$ that satisfies the following properties?

1. its domain is $\mathbb{R}$
2. $f'(x) > 0$ for all $x$
3. $f''(x) + (f'(x))^2 < 0$ for all $x$

The log function $\ln(x)$ gives some idea about conditions 2 and 3.  But for now, I did not find any example.

Besides, I want to find a non-linear differential function $f(x)$ defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and that is:

1. strictly increasing
2. (quasi)-concave

I think this is easier than the previous one. By looking at the graph, I guess this function exists, but I did not find one explicitly.

---

**EDIT 1**

Thank you for all the comments, especially by @mihaild. I have found an example for these questions. An example for the 2nd question is $-e^{-x}$. And an example for the 1st question is borrowing the idea of the 2nd one, which is the following.

If $f(x)=-e^{g(x)}$, then $f'(x)=-g'(x)e^{g(x)}$, $f''(x)=-g''(x)e^{g(x)}-(g'(x))^2e^{g(x)}$, and $f''(x)+(f'(x))^2=-g''(x)e^{g(x)}$. So we just need $g(x)$ is defined on $\mathbb{R}$ and satisfies:

1. $g'(x) <0$ for all $x$,
2. $g''(x) >0$ for all $x$

Then simply we choose $g(x)=e^{-x}$. So an example is $-e^{e^{-x}}$.

This is a wrong computation. I will try to fix it. $(f’(x))^2$ should be $(g’(x))^2 e^{2g(x)}$.

**EDIT 2**

After checking my previous example and reading all comments again. I see there does not exist a real function for the 1st question. (Thanks a lot for a remark in @mihaild comment.)

Indeed, assume that there exists $f(x)$ that satisfies the 1st condition. Then $g(x)=e^{f(x)}$ is a positive, strictly increasing and strictly concave function. But by its concavity $$g(x) \leq g(0)+ g'(0)x.$$
Since $g'(0)>0$, we have $\displaystyle\lim_{x \to - \infty}g(x) =-\infty$, which contradicts its positivity.

Comment: $\log(\log(x))$ *almost* works. It just doesn't satisfy the domain requirements...

Comment: @Joe yeah domain is the most important condition, that why I put it the first. Btw your example is very interesting. Thanks a lot. ^^

Comment: Thanks. Sadly I don't see an easy way of turning this into a proper solution. You can't just throw in an absolute value sign since $|x|$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Is the derivative given to be bounded

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi  yeah in my knowledge, its derivative should be finite. But u have an example with infinite derivative?

Comment: Could you show it? It may be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It was wrong @N.Quy

Comment: Does $-e^{-x}$ works for the second part? Also, logarithm of any positive function for the second part will work for the first part, but unfortunately there are no positive functions for the second part...

Comment: @mihaild, Thank you so much for your help. I forgot this function $-e^{-x}$. And your idea about the 1st part is right. I think about this idea too, that why I ask the 2nd part.

Comment: @N.Quy But $f(x)=-e^{e^{-x}}$ does not satisfy the 3rd condition of the first question. Have you checked if I am not wrong?

Comment: @manooooh you’re right, I made a mistake in computation of $(f’(x))^2)$

Comment: @N.Quy if such a function exists then the derivative must be bounded

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi, As I prove in EDIT 2, there does not exist a function for question 1.

Comment: As a physicist by education, I cannot make complete sense of your question. The main problem encountered at first sight
is: [dimensionality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dimensional_analysis#Percentages_and_derivatives). Let $f$ be position
and $x$ be time. Then $f'(x)$ is velocity and $f''(x)$ is acceleration. You cannot add acceleration to velocity squared
as in (3.).

Comment: What __is__ physically possible is to compare the general acceleration $f''(x)$
with a special acceleration, namely the one belonging to [Centripetal force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centripetal_force#Formulae)
: $a_c = [f'(x)]^2/f(x)$. Thus the following modification of statement (3.) might make sense physically.
$$
f''(x)f(x) + [f'(x)]^2 < 0 \quad \mbox{with} \quad [f^2(x)]'' = [2f(x)f'(x)]' = 2f''(x)f(x) + 2[f'(x)]^2
$$A mirror of my deleted answer is found [here](http://www.alternatievewiskunde.nl/jaar2021/2021feb05.htm).

Comment: @HandeBruijn Not everything (equations at least) can be made physically dimensional. In this case, both $f'$ and $f''$ can be viewed as dimensionless quantities where $x$ is a dimensionless number. This would make sense of $f''+f'^2$. For instance, imagine $f$ being a univariate function of a drag coefficient.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire. Anyway, I'm glad that my physics intuition is right and that such a function $f$ does not exist :-)

Comment: @HandeBruijn Thanks for offering the bounty! I've just realised that when constraint 3 is changed to $f''(x)+f'(x)<0$, there *is* a solution; for instance $f(x)=-\exp(-2x)/2$.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Let $g=1/f'$ so $g'>1,g>0\,\forall x\in \Bbb R$ which is impossible so such an $f$ does not exist.

Comment: That is very neat.

Comment: Why is it impossible for $g$ to satisfy $g'>1$ and $g>0$?

Comment: @Joe It will not be satisfied for all $x<-M$ for some $M>0$ since at every point, $g$ increases at least at fast at $x$ which means it is unbounded in both directions.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire: Oh, of course! This is a very elegant answer. $(+1)$.

Comment: @TheSimpliFire. I have decided to set a bounty on this exellent answer. Oh yeah, once you see it, it's simple. But the problem is in seeing it :-)

Comment: @TheSimpliFire what part of the question states that it needs to be unbounded?

Comment: Sorry I downvoted this by mistake. Please pardon my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to TheSimpliFire's solution (because I cannot comment), one can prove the assertion that a differentiable function from $\mathbb{R}$ to itself such that $g>0$ and $g'>1$ cannot exist by applying the mean value theorem to $g$, giving
\begin{equation}
|g(x)-g(y)|>|x-y| \text{ for all x,y}.
\end{equation}
By definition, the function is injective. Being continuous and injective it takes open sets to open sets. So $f(\mathbb{R})$ is open. Also, taking a sequence $(x_{n})$ converging to $x$ in $\mathbb{R}$ we observe that $f(x_{n})$ goes to $f(x)$ so $f(\mathbb{R})$ is closed. Being both open and closed in $\mathbb{R}$, $f(\mathbb{R}) = \mathbb{R}$.

The function is surjective, contradicting the fact that it can only take positive values.

Answer (score 0):

After TheSimpleFire's elegant solution. Is my reasoning simple and correct?:

Let $g(0)=N>0$. Then
$$\int_{-N-1}^0 g'(x)dx>\int_{-N-1}^0 1\;dx$$
$$g(0)-g(-N-1)>N+1$$
$$N-g(-N-1)>N+1$$
$$g(-N-1)<-1$$
contradicting the positivity of $g(x)$.